# angular ng-options with preselected value by object id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

Is there a way the following `select` can have a `pre-selected` club ?

```
<select ng-model="c.pilot.clubIdx" ng-options="club.idx as club.name for club in c.clubs track by club.idx">
```

c.pilot.clubIdx = 2 
c.clubs = { {idx: 1, name: "club1"}, {idx: 2, name: "club2"} }

The select-menu should show "club2".

Since the clubs are stored in a db and can be altered, I like to keep them only as `references` on the `pilots`.

SOLVED: removing track by solves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the controller set the ng-model of the select to the value of the option you want selected. Something like : `$scope.c.pilot.clubIdx = 2` or `$scope.c.pilot.clubIdx = $scope.c.clubs[1].idx`

Comment: thats the thing, c.pilot.clubIdx is allready value 2, but its not selected in the view.

Comment: @OlliiRenner can you create a plunker with this problem? there shouldn't be any problem setting the value of the select with this method, here's an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ygieal5wxbCwj0rlzTtN?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot.
adding the  track by option.id (in you case) re-creates the problem.
removing it in my case - solves it :)
i dont really understand why but angular docs says "Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression."

Comment: @OlliiRenner Ahh ok i see the problem now. Honestly i can't say that i completely understand but for some reason when you use the `track by` expression the value of each option is equal to the entire option object not just the id (in your case it's the `club` from `club in clubs`). So to set the default value you would need to set `c.pilot.clubIdx = c.clubs[1]` instead of just setting it to the value of the id.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="c.pilot.clubIdx" ng-options="club.idx as club.name for club   in c.clubs track by club.idx" ng-selected="(club.idx == 2)?true:false">
```

add ng-selected like so. It should be preselected

Comment: i think this only works if i add the ng-selected on a <option> tag, not on a <select>

Answer (score 0):

using underscore/lodash use the following lines in controller:

```
var club =_.where(c.clubs, {name:"club2"});
$scope.c.pilot.clubIdx = club.idx;
```

Answer (score 0):

removing the track by clause solves the problem. i dont fully understand why, but who knows. [angular doc for ngOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVJLq.png)