# Set first value as the deafult select box value

Tags: angularjs

html code to set a default drop down value. Had to set the first value in the list as the default selected value.

```
<div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TestController as regCtrl" >
 <div ng-init="regCtrl.getMasterData()" >
<select ng-model="regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId" ng-change="regCtrl.getType(regCtrl.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId)"
                                 ng-options="sctype.screeningTypeId as sctype.screeningType for sctype in regCtrl.screeningTypeList track by sctype.screeningTypeId"
                                 class="form-control field-size ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" name="screeningType"
                                 id="screeningType" required >
</div>
</div>
```

Below is the controller where I can set the value.

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app.controllers')
        .controller("TestController",  TestController);

    TestController.$inject = ['$http','LookupService','$filter', '$timeout', 'SweetAlertService', 'Constants'];
    function TestController($http,LookupService,$filter, $timeout, SweetAlertService, Constants){
        var vm = this;

                      vm.getMasterData = function(){             
                                     $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'master/getAllScreeningTypeMast'
            }).success(function(response){
                vm.screeningTypeList=response.result; 

            }).error(function(resp){

            });

            vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId[0].screeningTypeId; // getting undefined 
            }
})();
```

This is  the response from the server

```
/**
                        [{
        "screeningTypeId": 2,
        "screeningType": "Employment",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "Y"
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 3,
        "screeningType": "Female Marriage",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "N"
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 4,
        "screeningType": "Food",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": null
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 1,
        "screeningType": "Male Marriage",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "Y"
    }]

                */
```

Had tried ng-int,ng-selected nothing worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and write in .success function

vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = response.result[0];

This would work as in ng-option it store entire object. :)
 I have written a quick code related to your's:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="TestController" >
  <select ng-model="screeningTypeIdData" ng-options="op.screeningType for op in screeningTypeList track by op.screeningTypeId">

  </select>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

and .js file

// Code goes here

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller("TestController",['$scope','$http','$filter', '$timeout',function($scope,$http,$filter, $timeout)
{



    $scope.screeningTypeList =  [{
        "screeningTypeId": 2,
        "screeningType": "Employment",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "Y"
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 3,
        "screeningType": "Female Marriage",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "N"
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 4,
        "screeningType": "Food",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": null
    }, {
        "screeningTypeId": 1,
        "screeningType": "Male Marriage",
        "activeYn": null,
        "mmpidRequiredYn": "Y"
    }];

$scope.screeningTypeIdData  = $scope.screeningTypeList[0];
   // alert($scope.screeningTypeList[0].screeningTypeId);
  //alert($scope.screeningTypeIdData ) 

}]);
```

Comment: Tried this previously, got error "angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot set property 'screeningTypeId' of undefined"

Comment: Can we use fix with out changing the ng-model, as its using for binding.

Comment: can you provide fiddle of your code?? It will help to resolve quickly

Answer (score 1):

aren't you using the wrong variable to set your default value? as in instead of :

```
vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId[0];
```

it should be :

```
vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = vm.screeningTypeList[0];
```

the `vm.screeningTypeList` is the array containing the results. Also instead of setting the variable to just the id you should be setting it to the entire object

There was a similar problem here: [angular ng-options with preselected value by object id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643944/angular-ng-options-with-preselected-value-by-object-id/36644470#36644470)

This is caused by the `track by` in your `ng-options`.

Comment: 12477 TypeError: Cannot set property 'screeningTypeId' of undefined"

Comment: @user630209 probably because your attaching the `screeningTypeId` property to a non existent object (`vm.user.screeningType`). So either change the variable to be just `vm.screeningTypeId` or create the parent objects first before setting the value: `vm.user = { screeningType : {} }`

Answer (score 0):

```
vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId = vm.user.screeningType.screeningTypeId[0].screeningTypeId;
```

use above code in .success function not outside it.